# Join a specific boost thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I m creating about 300 boost threads in a process.
Is there any way to join a specific thread based on the thread id ?

Comment: How are you managing those threads? (You somehow remember the threads shot off, do you?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It heavenly depends on how you save the `boost::thread`s. If you save them in a container (with `T = boost::thread*`), you can simply use something like

```
for(iterator it = ctn.begin(); it != ctn.end(); ++it){
    if(it->get_id() == join_thread_id){
        it->join();
        break;
    }        
}
```

However, if you don't save your threads somewhere and just use `new boost::thread` without saving the pointer it's not possible since boost doesn't provide any automatic bookkeeping functionality.

1. Remark: Keep in mind that you'll need to use [`boost::thread::id`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.id) to save the id.
2. Remark: `std::map<boost::thread::id,boost::thread*>` might come in handy for such tasks.

Comment: or `find_if(begin(ctn), end(ctn), [join_thread_id](iterator it) { return it->get_id() == join_thread_id;});`

Comment: If there are a lot of threads, isn't better the map?. I'm asking this with performance in mind.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: It depends on the meaning of `a lot of`. A map scales nice with the number of arguments (sub-linear lookup complexity), but depending on the actual number of items, a small vector may outperform a small map.

Comment: @phresnel: I don't think that OP uses C++11, that's why I didn't use lambdas ;).

Comment: @AdriC.S.: Heavily depends on how many threads are going to be `join`ed manually. A single lookup will take O(log n) instead of O(n), however, it takes O(n log n)  to build the map instead of O(n). If there is only a small constant number a vector will be much faster, but if you join like half the threads a map is better.

Comment: These threads dont perform complex functionality .. primary purpose is to read messages on some queues and pass on to some other thread

Comment: @AdriC.S.: In theory yes, as map::find is O(log(N)) whereas finding in an unsorted vector would be O(N). In reality though if the size of the thread-objects is small enough you get the extrem benefit of caching which will make the vector faster than one would expect based on the O(..)-notation. Stroustrup recently compared std::list and std::vector in one of his recent talks that exemplifies why vector is most of the time the container you want to use..

Comment: @phresnel: In this case sri is creating 300 hundred threads. Since you suggested de `find_if` approach should I suppose that's better than the map?.

Comment: @MFH: Do you have a link to that talk or somewhere I can check it?. I'm interested in what Stroustrup said.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style

Comment: @AdriC.S.: Have a look: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style

Comment: @AdriC.S.: `find_if` is a standard library algorithm in C++ which works with any container. Whether a `map` or a `vector` or any other structure is optimal depends not only on the size of the container, but also on access patterns. In the end only real world test-runs can show you what performs better.